# How do I use all instances of a templated class?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, types, c++20

So I have a simple template class with multiple classes inheriting different types of it.

```
template<typename T> class root {
    T value;
};

class body : public root<int> {
    /* some code */
};

/*some more classes that inherits root*/
```

and later down in the file, I need to reference all classes that inherits from root

```
concept _bcie = std::is_base_of_v<root, body>
```

and it gives me the error `use of class template 'root' requires template arguments`

But I want to reference ALL classes that inherits from the root

Is there a way to just use the class without providing a template argument?

Comment: This will not work the way you want. You can't use `root` without giving it a template argument. `std::is_base_of_v` compares types, and `root<int>` is a completely different type than `root<char>` , etc.  You would have to make `_bcie` a template and pass its argument to `root`'s argument, which I'm guessing will probably break what you are attempting to do.  Can you please provide an example of what exactly you are trying to accomplish by "referencing all classes that inherit from `root`"? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: You do not state your use case, so not sure if it would be useful, but you could check whether the CRTP pattern would help.

Comment: @spectras "*you could check whether the CRTP pattern would help*" - which can be replaced with [Deducing this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) in C++23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use template lambda

```
template<typename T> 
class root {
  T value;
};

template<class T>
concept is_derived_from_root = requires (const T& t) {
  []<class U>(const root<U>&){}(t);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YoqTrnq3Y)

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer that I am searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Make `root` derive from another higher non-template base class, and check against that class.